# What is the name of the gain/cost ratio

Tags: microeconomics

I wanted to know what is the formal name of the (gain/cost)x100 ratio calculation (growth rate perhaps?). Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the gain in your ratio a net gain or a gross gain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call it a [benefit–cost ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefit%E2%80%93cost_ratio).

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to it as the '*Relative Gain*', possibly.